# Displaying SQL Script in Horizontal line

Tags: sql, pivot

I want to display SQL Script output in Horizontal line without using PIVOTING. I'm using SSRS2005 and it doesnt support Pivoting.

```
select ID, Name from Employee
```

Output:

```
1  Steve
2  Koka
3  Putin 
4  Barack
```

The question is I need this output in horizontal line like the following:

```
1         2        3        4
Steve    Koka    Putin    Barack
```

Comment: Search for pivot for your RDMS.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

For MS SQL try the below:

```
select [1],[2],[3],[4] 
from (select * from Empolyee) p 
pivot (max(Name) 
for ID in([1],[2],[3],[4])
) as pvt
```

Comment: Mohammed, I thank you for your response but I'm using SSRS2005 and it doesn't support PIVOTING. I think, Stored procedure is the only way.